# Differ between type errors

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I have a function say:

```py
def foo(a, b, c):
  ...
```

I can handle `TypeError` due to missing arguments like:

```py
try:
  foo(1, 2)
except TypeError:
  print("Arguments are not ok.")
```

The type error can be raised for many reasons like:

- Too many arguments
- Missing arguments
- etc.

The problem here is that I want to know if the error was raised because of less arguments provided or too many arguments provided.

Yes, I can check what the error message says using if statements but that seems kind of inefficient. Is there a better way and probably efficient of doing this?

Comment: What would you programmatically do with that information…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a workaround for this:

```py
import inspect

def foo(x, y, z):
   ...

args = (1, 2)
try:
  foo(*args)
except TypeError:
  fooargs = inspect.getfullargspec(foo).args

  if len(fooargs) > len(args):
    print('Less arguments passed')

  elif len(fooargs) < len(args):
    print('Too many arguments passed')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give each argument a default value and check for that, and also add a catchall

```py
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None, *_too_much):
    if a == None:
        pass  # argument-checks here
    ...
    if _too_much:
        pass  # Too many arguments handling here
```

Though, what is your use-case for this? More verbose handling of usage errors for interactive use or something else? If your user is not specifically using this in a REPL or something, there's probably a better way of doing what you want.

Comment: Seems mad to reinvent error handling that Python is already handling by itself…

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the intention behind this as Exception handling gives the clear reason for failure. But still if you need to do it then here is what might work for you:

```
try:
    # Call to the function
except TypeError as ex:
    if (re.search(r"missing.*positional argument", str(ex))):
        print ("Less no. of arguments passed")
    elif (re.search(r".*takes\s*\d+.*but.*were given", str(ex))):
        print ("Too many arguments passed")
    else:
        print ("Another error")
```